# Magento 2 Integration Test db-port

Tags: magento2, database, testing, integration-test

I've tried running Magento's built-in integration testing using MySQL:5.7 docker container on a different port.

`php bin/magento dev:tests:run integration`

Question is, how can I use a different port?

The following is my `dev/tests/integration/etc/install-config-mysql.php`

```
/**
* Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
* See COPYING.txt for license details.
*/

return [
    'db-host' => 'localhost',
    'db-port' => '33060', // <-- this is not working
    'db-user' => 'root',
    'db-password' => '',
    'db-name' => 'magento_integration_tests',
    'db-prefix' => '',
    'backend-frontname' => 'backend',
    'admin-user' => \Magento\TestFramework\Bootstrap::ADMIN_NAME,
    'admin-password' => \Magento\TestFramework\Bootstrap::ADMIN_PASSWORD,
    'admin-email' => \Magento\TestFramework\Bootstrap::ADMIN_EMAIL,
    'admin-firstname' => \Magento\TestFramework\Bootstrap::ADMIN_FIRSTNAME,
    'admin-lastname' => \Magento\TestFramework\Bootstrap::ADMIN_LASTNAME,
 ];
```

I also tried removing `'db-port' => '33060',` and replaced `'db-host' => 'localhost',` with `'db-host' => 'localhost:33060',` and still it doesn't recognize the host.

Also, I can succesfully connect to the MySQL server using Workbench.

Anyone know how to change the port reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be **impossible as of Magento 2.1**.

The database connection `\Magento\TestFramework\Db\Mysql` gets instantiated based on the configuration in `\Magento\TestFramework\Application::getDbInstance()`. The parameters are:

```
$host,
$user,
$password,
$dbName,
$this->getTempDir(),
$this->_shell
```

and that DB class does not use a port parameter anywhere.

So currently the only way around it is to forward the port to the default `3306`

**Good news is, there is a merged pull request:** https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/4275

So with **Magento 2.2** you will be able to use `'db-host' => 'localhost:33060',`

Comment: Thanks fab, that's what I've done. forward the port to the default 3306. Cheers!